# XAML viewer says to Update windows 1809, but I don't have any update

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp, windows-template-studio

I was busy for a while, so I couldn't work with UWP enough. : )...
Today, I made project with Windows Template Studio, a powerful template.
after I created it, I clicked a XAML page. but XAML design viewer shows message that I need to update to Windows 10, version 1809 ( 10.0.17763.0) to see the contents of XAML viewer.
[image]
but I'm worried that my laptop said that its windows version is up to date. **1803**
I'm a korean user, and if this problem will not be a long-term problem, and just localization problem with windows policy. then I would be happy and I would go to practice with building a tiny App.
[image]
but, if this problem is my problem. how can I update to windows 1809 or, just download SDK to solve this problem ? or can I degrade Windows template studio ?

### addded

if I make project with blank uwp app - target version 1803 -, XAML design viewer works well. but if i make blank uwp app with target version 1809, I get same error message.

Comment: ‍♂same issue for using 1809sdk you pc should also have installed same or higher version of windows 10 version, use Update tool ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/software-download/windows10 ) or downgrade sdk to 1803

Comment: thank you , @ShubhamSahu. after downloading and installing that you advised, but It still shows same error messaging. so I just change target version to 1803. thank you.

Comment: Okay, goto about in settings check you pc is updated to build 1809 or not, until you cant use build 1809 api and changes, however if you are targeting other device also e.g mobile which currently has version 10.0.15254.xxx build 1709

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Thank you, after reading your comment, I checked the version of my window os. It was 1803 still. So while wondering why it wasn't updated, I decided to re-update. after making enough storage space for updating and long updating prepare time with some of rebooting, I got a 0x800f008af - 0x20003 error messages. -_-;;  I think, yesterday also maybe I got same error messages, but I didn't notice it.. and I'm re-updating now. 3rd times. I hope this will be good. ^^..; thank you for mobile and 1709 information, also.

Comment: great, problem solved. and I'm happy to experience awesome features of 1809. Thank you.

Comment:  ..........same also happened with after 4th time it get updated successfully, enjoy new features (win+v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the solution in "Solution Explorer" and select "Retarget Solution". Set the Windows SDK version to 10.0.16299.0

Comment: Thank you. I was embarrassed at that time. I was not able to find "Retarget Solution". so, I opened "Properties" page in current project with Visual Studio, and I changed target version.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I installed only one sdk and that is why I was getting the above mentioned error. From VS installer I installed SDK support for each version and it worked fine for me and my machine is still on windows 10 1803 (I believe they haven't rolled out update for my machine).